# Spring Batch - beforeJob does not seem working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a job-listener like below:

```
@Component
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {
    
    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.STARTED) {
            log.info("Job Started... .!!!");
          // my logic
        } else {
            log.error("Job NOT Started... .!!!");
          // my logic
        }
    }

   @Override
   public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
      if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
          log.info("!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results");
          // my logic
   }
}
```

**afterJob** works just fine. No issues at all.

Problem: I can not see any of the message from **beforeJob**. What I am doing wrong or what is the missing link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `JobCompletionNotificationListener` listener to your job config

So in job config will be like this :

```
 @Bean
    public Job jobConfig(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step yourStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("nameJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(yourStep)
                .end()
                .preventRestart()
                .build();
    }
```

Hope useful

Comment: Silly me. After I verified afterJob, I commented that `listener(listener)` out. And never noticed that none (before/after) of the messages are showing up as I was pursuing beforeJob message and logic. I had  `listener(listener)`  in my JobConfig though. Not sure I should I delete this question or accept your answer as you answer is perfect and you spent your time too. I will wait for (any) moderator's comments before I perform any action on it. Thanks a ton anyways.

Comment: Hi @AjayKumar i have no problem if you accept or not my answer, just like you said i spent some time for this answer.